# Getting an element value based on some conditions in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

Below is my source XML where I need to get doc_id where doc_tag equals to "deliverable". In below example I need doc_id as 123654789 as doc_tag equals to deliverable, I tried various X paths but I couldn't exactly pin point on doc_tag as deliverable

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks
Venk

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <document>
        <doc_id>321654987</doc_id>
        <doc_tag>Log</doc_tag>
    </document>
    <document>
        <doc_id>123654789</doc_id>
        <doc_tag>deliverable</doc_tag>
    </document>
    <document>
        <doc_id>325698741</doc_id>
        <doc_tag>Log2</doc_tag>
    </document>
    <document>
        <doc_id>369852147</doc_id>
        <doc_tag>nondeliverable</doc_tag>
    </document>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you show any xpath expressions you have currently tried? Thanks!

Comment: `//document[doc_tag="deliverable"]/doc_id/text() ` selects doc_id value

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried this xpath    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="root/document/doc_tag='deliverable'"
    </xsl:template>

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include that template, as code is hard to read in comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value when you are in a template matching the document node

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="root/document[doc_tag='deliverable']/doc_id" />
</xsl:template>
```

The square braces represent a condition on which the selected `document` elements should be filtered.